# Java: Is there any way to implement shift on a boolean array? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, shift

I'm trying to shift a boolean array to the left, based on how many times the user wants the number to shift, but I have no idea if I can even shift an array. I know that I can shift integers, so should I convert the boolean array to an int, shift that, then convert it back to the array? That just seems like a lot of work for small results. If anyone has a solution, please help!!!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*shifting an array*"?

Comment: "Shifting" an array is not the same as shifting an int. To "shift" an array you'd possibly be adding/removing elements if the array wasn't large enough for the "shift" (A List comes to mind if you're really wanting to to this).

Comment: Various unix shells, perl, and other languages define "shift" on an array a as setting a[0]=a[1], a[1]=a[2] ... a[n-2] = a[n-1]. Then the n-1'th element is discarded. In java, this is most easily accomplished with an ArrayList. If the ArrayList is a, it's just a.remove(0).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean pretend an array of boolean values is a binary value, like an int, then bit shift it to the right of left.

Looking at an int value of 1, this happens

```
    int c = 1; 
    c <<= 1; // 10

    c = 1;
    c >>= 1; //0
```

To mimic that behaviour given that I have an array of boolean values (1/0) and I am inferring that it is representative to bits in a number.

This is how I would do it....

I'd create my own custom class using an ArrayDeque as a composite object, then add the shift functionality.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.lang.Boolean;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class BooleanArray{

     ArrayDeque<Boolean> number;

     public BooleanArray(Boolean [] nums){
           number  = new ArrayDeque<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(nums));
     }

     //  >>
     public void shiftRight(int times){

          while(times-- > 0){
           number.removeFirst();
           number.addLast(false);
          }
     }

     // << 
     public void shiftLeft(int times){

         while(times-- > 0) number.addFirst(false);

    }

    public String toString(){

      Iterator<Boolean> it = number.descendingIterator();
      String str = "";
      while(it.hasNext()){

        if(it.next()) str += "1";
        else str += "0";
      }

      return str;

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){

        int c = 1; 
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(c));
        c <<= 1;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(c));

        c = 1;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(c));
        c >>= 1;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(c));


        System.out.println("==========");
        Boolean [] cArr = {true};
        BooleanArray arr = new BooleanArray(cArr);
        System.out.println(arr.toString());

        arr.shiftLeft(1);
        System.out.println(arr.toString());

        arr = new BooleanArray(cArr);
        System.out.println(arr.toString());

        arr.shiftRight(1);
        System.out.println(arr.toString());

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward solution goes like this:

```
package snippet;


public class BooleanArrayShift {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] x = new boolean[] { true, true, true, true, true };
        for (int i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
            boolean[] result = shiftRight(x, i);
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            printBooleanArray(result);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
            boolean[] result = shiftLeft(x, i);
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            printBooleanArray(result);
        }
    }

    private static void printBooleanArray(boolean[] result) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        for (boolean b : result) {
            sb.append(b).append(",");
        }
        if (result.length > 0)
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.append("]");
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    private static boolean[] shiftRight(boolean[] bs, int n) {
        boolean[] result = new boolean[bs.length];
        n = Math.min(n, bs.length);
        System.arraycopy(bs, 0, result, n, bs.length - n);
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean[] shiftLeft(boolean[] bs, int n) {
        boolean[] result = new boolean[bs.length];
        n = Math.min(n, bs.length);
        System.arraycopy(bs, n, result, 0, bs.length - n);
        return result;
    }
}
```